# Manipulating and changing data for an App for test automation

Tags: android, iphone, proxy, appium

I am looking for ways to basically manipulate data that is shown  in my app by intercepting the API calls it makes and then basically manipulate the data ( positive and negative scenarios) and then observe how my App behaves. I have been manually intercepting these calls and doing it in Charles Proxy tool  but I want to get rid of it and looking for a way to do this through Automation. Set up my test data intercept the API calls through a proxy and then run my functional tests on the App. I am looking to do this for both Android and IPhone Apps.

Note: I have been using Appium for Automation.